# Foreign-key relationships with qml QTableView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

If I have a table that looks something like this (where QLSqlTableModel derives from QSqlRelationalTableModel):

```
QLSqlTableModel *employeeModel = new QLSqlTableModel(NULL, db);
employeeModel->setTable("Employee");
// employeeModel->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("Department", "id", "name"));
employeeModel->generateRoleNames();
employeeModel->select();
```

Then in the qml file:

```
TableView {
  model: employeeModel

  TableViewColumn {
    role: "DEPARTMENT_ID"
    title: "Dep."
  }
}
```

This seems to comply with the documentation [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#setRelation), except I am using Qt 5.1.  While the relationship should be replacing the department id with the name (when I remove the comments in the C++ code), instead it is blanking it out.